# Issue with Selenium: Unable to Load Webpage in Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, windows-11

I'm currently working on a project where I need to automate interactions with a web page using Selenium in Python. I've attempted to run one of the basic example scripts from https://selenium.dev, but it fails to work. I have installed Chrome Webdriver and set the environment variables; however, when I run the script, the Chrome window opens, but it does not navigate to the desired webpage. Here's the code -

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/web/web-form.html")

title = driver.title

driver.implicitly_wait(0.5)

text_box = driver.find_element(by=By.NAME, value="my-text")
submit_button = driver.find_element(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value="button")

text_box.send_keys("Selenium")
submit_button.click()

message = driver.find_element(by=By.ID, value="message")
text = message.text

driver.quit()`

The script runs without errors, but something is definitely wrong.
```

Selenium Version - 4.1.0
Chrome Version - 120.0.6099.71 (Official Build) (64-bit)
ChromeDriver version - Chrome for Testing v120.0.6099.71
Windows 11 - 23H2

I've tried using a modified version of the script with exception handling, but that changes nothing.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

# Initialize the webdriver with the chromedriver executable path
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

try:
    driver.get("https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/web/web-form.html")

    # Use WebDriverWait to wait for the elements to be present
    text_box = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, "my-text"))
    )

    submit_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button"))
    )

    # Perform actions
    text_box.send_keys("Selenium")
    submit_button.click()

    # Wait for the message element to be present
    message = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "message"))
    )

    text = message.text
    print("Message:", text)

finally:
    # Make sure to quit the driver in the finally block to ensure it is closed
    driver.quit()
```

Comment: Not sure I understand... you said 'it fails to work' but, you also said 'The script runs without errors, but something is definitely wrong.'

Comment: The trickiest thing when setting up Selinium is the web driver installation. Make sure you download and add it to the `PATH` environment variable. Try out other simpler example. Finally, I would recommend the `seliniumbase` package. It downloads and configures the driver by itself. And it has a cleaner APIs.

Comment: did you use `print()` to see what you get in `text` in first version?

Comment: did you run in console/terminal to see error messages?

Comment: your first version works for me and `print(text)` gives `Received!`. If you don't get any error message when you run it then I have no idea what is the problem. Or maybe problem is because you didn't use `print()` to display `text`. BTW: Selenium 4.15.2, Chrome 120.0.6099.71, ChromeDrive 120.0.6099.71, Linux Mint 21.2

Comment: I reviewed your code and executed it; the script ran perfectly fine. I believe any potential errors might be related to other factors and In the second code snippet that you provided, upon execution, were you able to observe the message 'Received!' in the console?

Comment: @journpy What I meant was that the Chrome window opens but no navigation takes place